# databases on (primary key & candidat key)

Tags: sql

If a table has only one key then we can say that  it is primary key as well as candidate key ??

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is **YES**. For more information, refer the below definition and link:

**Candidate Key** – A Candidate Key can be any column or a combination of columns that can qualify as unique key in the database. There can be multiple Candidate Keys in one table. Each Candidate Key can qualify as Primary Key.

**Primary Key** – A Primary Key is a column or a combination of columns that uniquely identify a record. Only one Candidate Key can be Primary Key.

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/10/22/sql-server-difference-candidate-keys-primary-key-simple-words/

Answer (score 0):

`Candidate Key` – A Candidate Key can be any column or a combination of columns that can qualify as unique key in database. There can be multiple Candidate Keys in one table. Each Candidate Key can qualify as Primary Key.

`Primary Key` – A Primary Key is a column or a combination of columns that uniquely identify a record. Only one Candidate Key can be Primary Key.

If a table has only one key it can be a primary or candidate depending on your idea.

More [Here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/10/22/sql-server-difference-candidate-keys-primary-key-simple-words/)